# How to show random feed from DB and show content in my site

Tags: plugins, php, feed

I try to get more than 3 feed from other web site and show it in my site like :

```
function fw_shortcode( $atts ) {

    global $wpdb, $feedtable;
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $feedtable . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");

    while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {  
        $rss = fetch_feed($row["weburl"]);
        if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : 

            $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(1);
            $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);

            foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :

                $code .= '  <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                                <div class="vendoritem">';
                $code .= '          <a href="' . esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ) . '"  target=' . "_blank".'>';
                $code .= '              <img width="300" height="225" src="' . get_first_image_url($item->get_description()) . '" class="img-responsive relat wp-post-image" style="background-color:#3498db;">';
                $code .= '          </a>
                                    <div class="vendoritem__details">
                                        <a href="' . esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ) . '" class="vendoritem__title" target=' . "_blank" . '>' . esc_html( $item->get_title() ) . '</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>';

            endforeach;

        endif;
        /* End Loop */
    }

    $code .= '</div>';

    return $code;

    wp_reset_query();

}
```

My problem is i need to shoe only random 3 feed from table. but **some time** show me 2 feed, Why !!, and if any feed not work, how can get other feed from DB

Comment: I can see that you've asked 17 questions, but they are all still open. Please update the status of those questions and close any of them if they have been solved (see e.g. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)) Note that you can also post an answer yourself and accept it to close it. I'm sure you got great solutions to some of your questions, that could benefit other readers as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this, but here are some suggestions:

- Make sure your feeds are **valid**, e.g. [here](https://validator.w3.org/feed/).
- In the case of `is_wp_error( $rss )` giving true, you can check the corresponding error message with `$rss->get_error_message()`.
- Develop with `WP_DEBUG` activated.
- Don't use `mysql_query()`, it's **deprecated** since PHP 5.5.
- Use the [`$wpdb` object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to fetch data from your custom table.
- **Escape/prepare** your SQL if it uses any user input, to avoid SQL injections.
- **Indent** your code to make it more readable.
- Remove the `wp_reset_query()` line, it's doing nothing after the `return`.

Then update your question accordingly with more info. Thanks.

Comment: all feed are valid and there are no error and my sql not have any sql-injection

Comment: Is that the case when only 2 items show up, instead of 3? You could use an `else` to print out the possible error messages. @ZamalekMan

Comment: if its show me 2 item. i need code to get one item to complete 3 item

Comment: You could fetch e.g. 6 urls instead of 3 and if a feed fails, you can try another one. Another approach would be to do this recursively. @ZamalekMan